# Problems with enumitem and calc

Tags: enumitem, calc

Below is a MWE with the `calc` and `enumitem` packages:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Section}
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\widthof{8.88.\ },label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic*.},leftmargin=!,ref=\thechapter.\arabic*]

\item Een
\item Twee

\end{enumerate}

\setbox0\hbox{8.88.\ }

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\wd0,label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic*.},leftmargin=!,ref=\thechapter.\arabic*]

\item Een
\item Twee

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If I compile this, the first `enumerate` environment creates an error, the second not.
But if I reverse loading the `calc` and `enumitem` packages, the error disappears. I couldn't find anything in the documentation of both packages. So what is the problem?

Comment: `calc` does a lot of changes to `\setlength` and `\setcounter` etc; Other packages change or rely on specific features of those register changing macros and introduce new behaviour. If `calc` is loaded afterwards, the changes are lost and the package macros do not work at all or not in the desired manner. In my opinion, it is best to load `calc` very early!

Comment: This MWE was distiiled from a TeX of several 100 lines of code. I compiled it 6 month ago without problems.

Comment: Yes, but I remember there was an update to `enumitem` on 2018/11/30, so quite recently updated. So there might be a change...

Comment: enumitem uses internally a command \enit@setlength. This is set as `\let\enit@setlength\setlength` so it will use the \setlength definition valid when the package is loaded.